# Looping through every commit in Git repository with LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I tried looping through `new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(path).Commits`, but it seems it only goes through the commits in the master (or I guess wherever the HEAD points to?).

How would I loop through every commit in the repository, regardless of what branch it is in and loop through them in order of when the commits occurred (date)?

I'm doing this for a purpose like `git log`, to list commits regardless of the branches, in order of date.

Bonus points if I could also loop through the commits that are not referenced (i.e. if you `git reset` away from some commits and the commits are no longer referenced and about to get gc'd).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for `git log --all` should be achievable with the following syntax

```
using (var repo = new Repository(yourRepoPath))
{
      var commits = repo.Commits.QueryBy(new Filter { Since = repo.Refs });
}
```

The `Filter` also exposes a `SortBy` property to control the ordering of the results. Default sorting (`GitSortOptions.Time`) will output the most recent commits first.

> Bonus points if I could also loop through the commits that are not referenced

There's no way to access the commits in the reflog nor the dangling one (yet?). Then, no bonus points, I guess :-)

Comment: That worked! But I'd like to understand why... if `repo.Commits` did not contain all of them, then how come after a `QueryBy` it now contained the remaining commits?

Comment: *There's no way to access the dangling commits (yet?).*
That's fine. Do you think that will be possible in the future? I guess it would be sort of like `git reflog` but skipping the non-commit ones.

Comment: `repo.Commits` is a shortcut to `repo.Commits.QueryBy(new Filter { Since = repo.Head })`. It's similar to `git log`

Comment: Dangling commits would require something similar to `git fsck --unreachable`. `git reflog` *should* be part of LibGit2Sharp v0.10.0

Comment: I'll wait for the v0.10.0 release then :)

Comment: using version 0.13, the usage `Filter` generates a warning: `'LibGit2Sharp.Filter' is obsolete: 'This type will be removed in the next release.`
 What is the recommended alternative?

Comment: @p.campbell The deprecated `QueryBy` method should point one to use the `QueryBy(CommitFilter)` overload instead.